# How to set value from different field or collection from specific document in Mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have colection "ttn_data" with doc:

```js
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("Some_different_ID"),
 "dev_id" : "e0e1e20102030405",
 "payload_fields" : {"temp_C" : 28.308}
}
```

and collection "records" with doc

```js
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5ed8af72c377d5b209597981"),
 "temp_C_different" : ""
 
}
```

I would like to set temp_C_different value from temp_C in ttn_data collection so the return after update query would be

```js
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5ed8af72c377d5b209597981"),
 "temp_C_different" : "28.308"
 
}
```

I try this method:

```js
try {    db.records.updateMany(       {  "_id" : ObjectId("5ed8af72c377d5b209597981") },   
                               { $set: { "temp_C_different" : db.ttn_data.temp_C.value } }    ); }
                               catch (e) {    print(e); }
```

but it sets "temp_C_different"value to some metadata info from database. What is the write way to do that kind of update?

Comment: How two of the collections related to each other?

Comment: They are not related, just two separete tables One teble generated by TTN bridege, other for interfacing Client app. They both are on the same Database